# Obtain %cpu usage: is this script correct?

Tags: python, linux, monitoring

I found this python script which seems to do the job, but I don't know if it is really correct and I can't explain myself that 100- in the last lines.

Theory behind it is clear: you sum up user,system and i/o time spent by the cpu, and you divide it for the same sum plus the idle time. This would give you a % of the cpu load.

I don't need a 100% accurate measurement, but just some hint about the real %cpu usage.

```
import time

TIMEFORMAT = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"
INTERVAL = 2

def getTimeList():
   statFile = file("/proc/stat", "r")
   timeList = statFile.readline().split(" ")[2:6]
   statFile.close()
   for i in range(len(timeList))  :
     timeList[i] = int(timeList[i])

   return timeList

def deltaTime(interval)  :
   x = getTimeList()
   time.sleep(interval)
   y = getTimeList()
   for i in range(len(x))  :
      y[i] -= x[i]
   return y

if __name__ == "__main__"  :
   while True  :
      dt = deltaTime(INTERVAL)
      timeStamp = time.strftime(TIMEFORMAT)
      cpuPct = 100 - (dt[len(dt) - 1] * 100.00 / sum(dt)) #why 100 - ?
      print timeStamp + "\t" + str('%.4f' %cpuPct)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 100 is 100%.  The expression yields time idle, you want time busy.  Subtract from 100.